# What does the draggable feedback disappear when the child column is passed stretch

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my first time using the Draggable Widget and I came across an issue where the feedback widget disappears when the feedback contains a column with the attribute `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,`.

When I remove this line the Draggable widget works as expected, but I need the widget to look the same when it is being dragged and when it is not. The widget is designed to stretch across the width available on the screen, but I'm thinking once it is being moved that constraint is gone? I'm not entirely sure but here is a demo and a simplified version of the code to repeat the problem.

Sorry in advance for the large `gifs` when I compress them with the size tag on Stack Overflow the gifs don't play.

With `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` in feedback:

[image: With Stretch Attribute]

Without `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` in feedback, but looses full width:

[image: Without Stretch Attribute]

Simplified Code:

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Draggable(
        axis: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Testing",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        feedback: Card(
          child: Column(
            // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // THIS LINE
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Testing",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        childWhenDragging: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  child: null,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  child: IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    tooltip: 'Delete Task',
                    color: Color(0xFFFF6984),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `LayoutBuilder` and passed on the `BoxConstraints` to a `ConstrainedBox` for the `Draggable` in feedback mode:

```dart
class MessageDraggable extends StatelessWidget {
  final Message message;

  const MessageDraggable({Key key, this.message}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Draggable<Message>(
          data: message,
          feedback: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: constraints,
            child: MessageCard(message: message),
          ),
          child: MessageCard(message: message),
          childWhenDragging: Container(),
          maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
          dragAnchor: DragAnchor.child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```